# ayuda al capturar datos con $(this).val();

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo este código.

```
$.post("tipo_documentos/llenar_combo",{accion:''},function(data){
    $("#documento").append(new Option('Seleccione',''));
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#documento").append(new Option(data[i][1],data[i][0],data[i][6]));

    };
    //$('#documento option[value="6').prop("selected", true);
},'json');
```

como veran en new option tengo 3 datos `data[i][1]` que es el nombre.
`data[i][0]` que es el codigo y `data[i][6]` que es el tipo_documento

Ahora tengo este otro código donde capturo los datos y los muestro en inputs:

```
$("#documento").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val()!="") {

        var codigo = $(this).val();                   
        var nombre = $("#documento option:selected").text();

        if (codigo == '07'|| codigo == '08')
          {
          $("#note").show();
          } else {
          $("#note").hide();
          }                  
        $("#nomb").val(nombre);           
        $("#cod").val(codigo);
        $.post("ventas/datos_documento" , {Codigo:codigo,Nombre:nombre} , function(data){
            $("#serie").val(data.Serie);
            $("#numero").val(data.Numero);             

        },'json');
    }else{
        $("#serie").val('');
        $("#numero").val('');                   
    }
});
```

el var codigo me captura el codigo y el var nombre el nombre pero como capturo el tipo_de documento ?

Comment: Hay un montón de ids referenciados en el selector de jquery, necesitaríamos ver también el código html al que se refieren esos ids.

Comment: solo es: var codigo = $(this).val();                   
        var nombre = $("#documento option:selected").text();

Comment: y esto lo muestra   $("#nomb").val(nombre);           
        $("#cod").val(codigo);

Comment: La sintaxis de new Option es new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected), los dos últimos parámetros son booleans (true/false) simplemente NO los puedes usar para añadir alguna especie de atributo que después desees capturar.

Comment: el  var nombre = $("#documento option:selected").text(); me captura el valor de data[i][1]

Comment: el var codigo = $(this).val();  me captura el valor de data[i][0]

Comment: solo quiero saber como capturar el data[i][6]

Comment: probe con var tipo_documento = $(this).val(2) y no funciona

Comment: No te está capturando `data[i][1]` simplemente te esta capturando el texto del `option:selected` el cual se ingresa en el primer parámetro de `new option()`, lo mismo que `.val()` que captura el `value` del `option:selected` no `data[i][0]`... si lees mi comentario arriba te estoy diciendo que `new option()` no te va a agregar un 'tercer' texto a ningún lado por lo cual no lo vas a capturar

Comment: ya te entendi amigo entonces como se podria hacer para obtener ese tercer elemento?

Comment: o simplemente no es posible ?

Comment: Ya te hice una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te decía en los comentarios [new Option()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) por sí solo no te va a agregar un "tercer" atributo a tu `<option>`, por lo cual debes agregarlo manualmente utilizando el método `.attr()` de **jQuery**.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo funcional, si tienes alguna duda puedes preguntar:

```js
$("#documento").append(new Option('Seleccione',''));
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    $("#documento").append($(new Option('Opción ' + i, i)).attr('tipo', 'tipo ' + i));
};

$("#documento").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val()!="") {
        var codigo = $(this).val();                   
        var nombre = $("#documento option:selected").text();
        var tipo = $("#documento option:selected").attr('tipo');
        
        console.log('El código es: ' + codigo + '\nEl nombre es: ' + nombre + '\nEl tipo es: ' + tipo);

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="documento"></select>
```

Utilizando tu código sería de la siguiente manera:

```
$.post("tipo_documentos/llenar_combo",{accion:''},function(data){
    $("#documento").append(new Option('Seleccione',''));
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#documento").append($(new Option(data[i][1],data[i][0])).attr('tipo', data[i][6]));

    };
    //$('#documento option[value="6').prop("selected", true);
},'json');

$("#documento").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val()!="") {

        var codigo = $(this).val();                   
        var nombre = $("#documento option:selected").text();
        var tipo = $("#documento option:selected").attr('tipo');

        if (codigo == '07'|| codigo == '08')
          {
          $("#note").show();
          } else {
          $("#note").hide();
          }                  
        $("#nomb").val(nombre);           
        $("#cod").val(codigo);
        $.post("ventas/datos_documento" , {Codigo:codigo,Nombre:nombre} , function(data){
            $("#serie").val(data.Serie);
            $("#numero").val(data.Numero);             

        },'json');
    }else{
        $("#serie").val('');
        $("#numero").val('');                   
    }
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo :D te daria un beso si te tuviera cerca me salvaste muchas gracias

Comment: @FernandoAbelGonzalesCh Jajajaja de nada, cuando tengas preguntas no dudas en hacerlas también puedes pasar por el [chat] cuando tengas preguntas que se basen en opiniones y no sean bien recibidas en el sitio, saludos